# Docclass {article}: changing {exam} class to {article} produces log errors

Tags: article, control, sequence

The mwe below compiled without error until I made this change:

Original: `\documentclass[12pt]{exam}`

Revision: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`

Changing from `{exam}` to `{article}` causes these  2 related errors:

`Undefined control sequence`

`l.53  \pagestyle{head}`

`No \begin{document} command was found.`

**The `\begin{document}` is in the same place as before the revision.**

Thank you for taking time to assist me!

mwe

````
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
%--code lines #4-6 show grid lines for page layout. Don't use in a real document!
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}       % <---
\pgfplotsset{GRID/.style = {    % define common style for images
    width=100mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
    grid=both,
    grid style={draw=gray!25},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=black!50, inner sep=1pt},
    xmin=-10,   xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
    xtick distance=2,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor tick num=1,
    tick align=outside,
            }}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

%added
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}     
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\restorebox              
\newenvironment{restoretext}%
    {\@parboxrestore%
     \begin{adjustwidth}{-3em}{}%
                \begin{lrbox}{\restorebox}%
                \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
        \usebox\restorebox
        \end{adjustwidth}
     }
\makeatother     
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\settasks{
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=0.75em,    % <---
 }
 \pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{Algebra II: Quadratic Systems}}
{}
{ 04/17/23}

\begin{document}

\textbf {SET A: Solve each system by graphing.}

\begin{tasks}(2)   
%Prob #1
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-5, y=-2x-9}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}

%Prob #2
  \task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-3, y=x+7}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}

\bigskip
%Prob #3
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=2(x-3)^2+1, 2x+y=11}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}
%Prob #4
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=\frac{1}{2}(x-4)^2-3, y=2x-11}$\\
\medskip
\begin{restoretext}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[GRID]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{restoretext}
\end{tasks}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: the error is `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \undefinedpagestyle 
                               
l.53  \pagestyle{head}`  as you use a page style you have not defined followd by `! Undefined control sequence.
l.54 \header` as you have not defined `\header`

Comment: well article.cls doesn't know the pagestyle and the \header command. You will to remove them or to define them.

Comment: @Ulrikefischer Thank you! But why would changing the doc class from {exam} to {article} cause this error? Also, I removed ```\pagestyle{head}``` command. That eliminated 1 error. But could you please peruse the code and explain why the ```No \begin{document} command was found``` appears. I believe I placed the ```begin{document}``` in the same place as my other projects which compile correctly.

Comment: why not? A class can define new commands if it wants. And also remove the `\header` together with the following arguments.

Comment: Perhaps adding `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` early in the Preamble would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exam class defines its own headers and styles, which are different from the article class. Thus `\pagestyle{head}` produces an irrecoverable error and the compilation collapses.

The problem goes away if you replace

```
\pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{Algebra II: Quadratic Systems}}
{}
{ 04/17/23}
```

with

```
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\normalfont\textbf{Algebra II: Quadratic Systems}\hfill  04/17/23}
```

Since `exam` loads the class `article`, the solution (for this page) will work for both classes.

Comment: I have been struggling to identify / solve the aforementioned error for over a year. And you found the solution without even being asked. Yours is the kind of generosity our trouble world so desperately needs. Thanks so much!